# I installed python module which the directory is not on PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, path

I tried to install some module for python, but when I install it using `pip`, this warning occurred

```
WARNING: The scripts jupyter-migrate.exe, jupyter-troubleshoot.exe and jupyter.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I've tried to add new PATH, but this warning still there. there are also option to ignore the warning but i don't know if that will mess up the module or not in the future.

Comment: Do you have this directory "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts" in your PATH?

Comment: the question is: should you care about the warning? the answer is: it depends. Are you able to *use* the packages that give the warning during installation? -> I'd say, just ignore the warning. If not, check your Python installation and how your environment variable "PATH" is configured.