# Error running jupyterlab via pip install in python 3.9

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, jupyter-lab

Hello I am fairly new to Python and I'm trying to get started with data visualization. I pip installed jupyter lab but it gave the error of  jupyter-troubleshoot.exe and jupyter.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p  which is not on PATH. I have had problems in the past with accessing csv files using VSCode so I think there might be an issue with my directory. How do I change this to PATH so the jupyterlab runs?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain in detail how you try to start JupyterLab? The message that you cite appears to be just a warning, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402711/i-installed-python-module-which-the-directory-is-not-on-path and in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402711/i-installed-python-module-which-the-directory-is-not-on-path. Have you tried to actually start jupyter lab after installation?

Comment: As for solving this warning, see https://superuser.com/questions/1372793/the-script-is-installed-in-directory-which-is-not-path

Comment: @Cass -For installing the python module "jupyterlab" in VS Code, please use the command "[pip install jupyterlab](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab/)", and the location where it is stored is "_\Lib\site-packages\_" of the currently used python environment.